# SARIMA model Parameters - Python

Tags: time-series, python, arima, autocorrelation

I am confused as how to extract the parameters of the SARIMA model by just looking at the graphs of ACF and PACF. For instance, by inspecting the graphs as shown [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/examples/notebooks/generated/statespace_sarimax_stata.html), how can I discover the parameters p,d,q,P,D,Q,s? Any help is extremely appreciated

Note: For convenience, I have taken a snapshot of the graphs from the above article:

[image]

Comment: The ACF doesn't decay that quickly, which indicates non-stationarity. I would start by taking a first difference on the data. Obtain the periodoram to identify the period. After that obtain the correlograms of the differenced data to see what seasonal difference is necessary. Then you can start looking at estimating parameters. 

Let me know how it goes and I will check in again to see if you have made some progress @Fabiana

Comment: @Stochastic  Thanks for the reply. Initially, I just needed help to understand info from the graphs. But you mentioned some interesting information. I will try to obtain the dataset and perform the operations you suggested. But is it the case that SARIMA should only be applied to Stationary data?